# String format query

Tags: java

What does it represents in java?

```
String.format("%01000d",0)
```

It prints 0 thousands times. But can anyone help how does it actually works. What does "%01000d" represents?

Comment: Please keep your question post 'rant free', thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument is a format string, here you can find the sintax:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax